# How to enable mobile broadband in networkmanager applet

Tags: gnome, gnome3, usb-modem

I am using Gnome 3.8 desktop. as a previous Gnome 2 user i know that to enable mobile broadband by entering the context menu with Alt + right click.

However with Gnome 3 i am unable to do so .

Please note that my usb modem works with sakis3g and wvdial and i have modemmanager installed. and mobile broadband works well with them i need to configure the networkmanager applet in Gnome 3 to work with my 3g USB modem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching through the awesome Archlinux forums i found the answer

First reinstall ModemManager

```
sudo pacman -S modemmanager
```

Then enable the modemmanager service

```
sudo systemctl enable ModemManager
```

note that the two M's are captialised

Then start the modem manager service

```
   systemctl start ModemManager
```

and restart your PC

```
 systemctl reboot
```